# Does the kernel of every alternating form contain a decomposable element?

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, tensor-rank, tensor-decomposition

Let $V$ be a real $n$-dimensional vector space, and let $1 < k < n$.

Let $\alpha \in \bigwedge^k (V^*) \cong (\bigwedge^k V)^*$. Thinking of $\alpha$ as a linear functional $\bigwedge^k V \to \mathbb{R}$, does $\ker \alpha$ always contain a (non-zero) decomposable element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(v_1, \ldots, v_{k+1})$ be a linearly independent family of vectors of $V$.

Let $W=\mathbb{R}v_k+\mathbb{R}v_{k+1}$, and consider the map $\beta: w \in W \longmapsto \alpha(v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{k-1} \wedge w$.

$\beta$ is a linear form on $W$ (which has dimension $2$), hence has a non-trivial kernel element $w$, and $\alpha(v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{k-1} \wedge w)=0$, and $v_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge v_{k-1} \wedge w \neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you! This answer is perfect-very elegant indeed.  I wonder how did you think about this...By the way, do you have an idea whether or not every codimension one subspace of $\bigwedge^k V$ contain a non-zero decomposable element? (you have explicitly used the fact that it was the kernel of some element in $\bigwedge^k V^*$, but I don't know if every codimension one subspace of $\bigwedge^k V$ can be realized as a kernel in this way).

Comment: Almost by definition, any subspace with codimension $1$ of any vector space is the kernel of a linear form. To keep the proof above working, codimension $ \leq n-k$ would continue to work.

Comment: Thank you, you are right of course, I was confused...I think that I see how to adapt the proof to the case of codimension$\le n-k$ as you said, by using more linear functionals and realizing our subspace as an intersection of their kernels...is that what you meant?

Comment: This is indeed what I meant.